# Why are the if conditions not being executed?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

This is a menu driven program asking for user's choice. 
Why are if conditions not executed? 
Output is attached.
Creating a program asking for user's input:

```
void main()
{  
    float a,b,ans=0;char ch,choice;


    choice='y';

    while(choice=='Y'||choice=='y')
    {


        printf("Enter two numbers \n");
        scanf("%f %f",&a,&b);
        printf("1.+for Addition\n");
        printf("2.-for subtraction \n");
        printf("3.*for multiplication \n ");
        printf("4./for Division \n");
        printf("Enter your choice of operation \n");
        scanf("%c",&ch);

        if(ch=='+')
            ans=a+b;
        else if (ch=='-')
            ans=a-b;
        else if(ch=='*')
            ans=a*b;
        else if(ch=='/')
            ans=a/b;
        else
        {
            printf("wrong choice entered\n");
        }
        printf("Answer is %f \n",ans);
        printf("Do you want to coninue (Y/N)\n");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
    }

    printf("program Terminated\n");
}
```

Output:

```
/* Enter two numbers
   1010
   22
   1.+for Addition
   2.-for subtraction
   3.*for multiplication
   4./for Division
   Enter your choice of operation
   wrong choice entered
   Answer is 0.000000
   Do you want to coninue (Y/N)
   n
   program Terminated
 */
```

The above is the output screen.
It doesn't perform operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input first 2 numbers, they are placed into variables a and b. BUT after entering those 2 numbers, you pressed enter. Computer sees that as new input and place it in first next appropriate variable that requires input. In this case it's your variable ch, and instead of +,-./ or *, ch has value of "new line". If you try to write value of ch on standard output as an integer, it will write number 10. It's ASCII character of new line. Simply adding `getchar()` after inputting first 2 numbers will collect that new line sign, and your next scanf will work properly.

By the way, you have same problem with your last input `scanf("%c",&choice);` because pressing enter after previous operation decision, will also cause your program not to work properly. Do the same thing for this part, or simply leave blank character before %c.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
      ^^
```

and

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
      ^^
```

Otherwise a next character is read that can be a white space character.

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf() does not consume trailing newlines. The skipped scanf() receives the newline from the previous line typed by the user and terminates without receiving more input as you would expect...

scanf() is a bit cumbersome with newlines. A possible solution would be to use fgets() to get a line from the console and then employ sscanf() to parse the received string.

Another, more targeted, solution would be to use " %c" in the format string of the last scanf() call. The %c format specifier does not consume leading whitespace on its own, which is why it gets the remaining newline, rather than a character typed by the user.